# SQL - select max between multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have the same type of item in different groups. I have to find the group that has the most of each item.

First things first, here is the data:

```
Count_of_Items | Group_ID | Item_Type

15|01|A
35|02|A
25|03|A
 3|01|B
 5|04|B
```

etc...

In this case, group 02 has the highest number of type A items (35) and group 04 had the most highest number of type B items.

I tried

```
    select max(count_of_items), Group_ID , item_type 
      from foo
     group by Group_ID, item_type
```

but that didn't work.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

***Using MS Sql Server 2005**

Comment: Can you try just grouping by the group ID?

Comment: What is supposed to be selected if two or more groups have the same item count value for the same item type? In addition: Can you provide a fiddle on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Grouping only by group_id didn't work, it produced more output than I needed; I guess I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should work

```
select f.* 
from foo as f inner join
maxforGroup(
    select max(count_of_items) maxC, item_type 
    from foo
    group by item_type
) as m
on f.Count_of_Items=m.maxC and f.item_type =m.item_type
```

Comment: Thanks, works a treat (note, I did have to remove maxforGroup neither SQL Server 2005 nor MySql 5.5.32 liked it)

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afdea/8/0

(Never heard of SQL Fiddle before, really neat)

Comment: @AfterWorkGuiness Please note that this solution will result in multiple rows for the same item type if two or more different groups have the same item count for this type. See [an updated version of your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19cbf/1). This may be the desired result, but this can't be told from the question.

Comment: Thanks; that is not a desired result, but I was going to wrap a query around this to select the min group ID.